# How to get the number of rows between hlines for orgmode table formula?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In my orgmode table formula, i would like to get the number of rows between hlines (for example: @I..@II). Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use calc's `vlen` operator to get the number of elements this way:

```
| Title |
|-------|
| row 1 |
| row 2 |
| row 3 |
|-------|
| 3     |
#+TBLFM: @5$1=vlen(@I..@II)
```